# How to prepare rectangle type tab bar in swift?

Tags: xcode, user-interface, swift3, uibutton, uitabbar

I have prepared a tab bar which has a square shape rectangle but I can't able to prepare a rectangle type shape of a tab bar button or UIButton or View. How can I prepare a tab bar or button or view as following gif file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like given below for each button:

```
let tabBar1Path = UIBezierPath()
```

`let tabBar1Layer = CAShapeLayer()`

`tabBar1Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))`

`tabBar1Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view!.frame.size.width * 0.25, y: 0))`

`tabBar1Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view!.frame.size.width * 0.2, y: tabBarHeight))`

`tabBar1Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tabBarHeight))`

`tabBar1Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))`

`tabBar1Layer.path = trianglePath.cgPath`

`tabBar1Layer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`

`tabBarButton1.layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)`